# Color every character differently

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am using KK Countdown to countdown to Xmas for a site.

I have a design which I have to follow that has each letter of the day countown with a blue background and border radius.

Right now the html is output like this

```
<span class="kkcount-down" data-time="1387929600">
     <span class="kkcountdown-box">
          <span class="kkc-dni">169</span>
          <span class="kkc-dni-text">DAYS </span>
          <span class="kkc-godz">23</span>
          <span class="kkc-godz-text"> </span>
          <span class="kkc-min">19</span>
          <span class="kkc-min-text"> </span>
          <span class="kkc-sec">48</span>
          <span class="kkc-sec-text">HOURS</span>
     </span>
</span>
```

The class kkc-dni is the part I am trying to target here.

I want to add a background colour to each letter inside that span.

Preferably with CSS. Is this possible?

I have used CSS before to style the first letter of paragraphs before but this is quite different and I cannot find any information on it.

Any suggestions?

Note: Because I am using a plugin to do this countdown I am not sure if I can change the way it outputs the spans and html. If I could wrap each letter in a span I would.

Comment: I think that is not possible only with CSS. You have the `:first-letter` pseudo-element... But each letter, I think that isn't possible.

Comment: you'd have to grab the content of the span jQuery('.kkc-dni').html(), then iterate over each letter String.split(""), then add each letter to  its own span. to go further into explanation, would have to know more about how you want to color each letter

Comment: Thank you Marc, yes I thought that this would be possible with some jQuery. Was hoping that there would be a CSS selector for each character

Comment: you could also do something clever if the font is fixed width.  you could make a background image with the colors you need.

Comment: Thanks Marc, think I will do some jQuery and wrap each character. 
Feel like I have more control that way as opposed to an image.

Good idea though!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> *I want to add a background colour to each letter inside that span.*

## Using an array of colors:

```js
const colors = ["#0bf", "#f0b", "#fb0", "#b0f"];

$('.kkc').find('span').each(function() {

  const text = $(this).text();
  const len = text.length;
    
  const newCont = [...text].reduce((a, ch, i) => 
    a + `<span style="background:${colors[i % colors.length]}">${ch}</span>`, ""
  );

  $(this).html(newCont);

});
```

```css
.kkcountdown-box>span>span {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="kkc">
  <span class="kkc-dni">169</span>
  <span class="kkc-dni-text">DAYS </span>
  <span class="kkc-godz">23</span>
  <span class="kkc-godz-text"> </span>
  <span class="kkc-min">19</span>
  <span class="kkc-min-text"> </span>
  <span class="kkc-sec">48</span>
  <span class="kkc-sec-text">HOURS</span>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

The above will, wrapping every single letter into a separate `span` will also add a background color from your Array list of colors.
Once the colors list end is reached will start from the first one and so on.

## Using a random color:

```js
$('.kkc').find('span').each(function() {

  const text = $(this).text();
  const len = text.length;
    
  const newCont = [...text].reduce((a, ch, i) => {
    const color= '#'+ (Math.random() * 0xffffff).toString(16).substr(-6); 
    return a + `<span style="background:${color}">${ch}</span>`
  }, "");

  $(this).html(newCont);

});
```

```css
.kkcountdown-box>span>span {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="kkc">
  <span class="kkc-dni">169</span>
  <span class="kkc-dni-text">DAYS </span>
  <span class="kkc-godz">23</span>
  <span class="kkc-godz-text"> </span>
  <span class="kkc-min">19</span>
  <span class="kkc-min-text"> </span>
  <span class="kkc-sec">48</span>
  <span class="kkc-sec-text">HOURS</span>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

The above will get every letter inside a `<span>` and wrap it into a new `span` with a randomly generated background color.

Comment: Looks good, except that it does not target the numbers only the letters, and I am trying to target the numbers.

The live demo works though so I am thinking it is something to do with kkcountdown

Comment: Still does not work.

Have made a jsBin but that does not output how it does on my page

http://jsbin.com/oranep/1/edit

Comment: @ChrisG-Jones look if you cannot create a demo, than create a fn and put my code into it. Execute that function than inside your plugin.

Comment: This is what I see on my site http://jsbin.com/oranep/4/

Guessing this is something to do with the countdown plugin.

Have played around with your code with different instances and it works fine. It's like the numbers are being pulled in from somewhere and cannot be targeted with your code or something...they update live on the page so that could be something to do with it? Have marked this as answered though because it does what I asked just does not work in my instance. Thanks for your help

Comment: @ChrisG-Jones the numbers are created inside a SPAN as TEXT, so no matter if the mumber changes, the SPAN is the same. So unminify the plugin and play around. `c` variable is the created SPAN, you can target it inside the plugin.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but I thought that with what you have done, you take what has been outputted and then break it down and add the spans around it. If the time changed and a number flicked over you would need to run your function again to add the span to the new number?

Answer (score 3):

You cannot style each letter of word without individually wrapping characters. This is the simple answer to the question, especially as asked in the the title.

However, the wrapping can be done with server-side scripting, or with client-side scripting. If this is acceptable, you should reformulate your question.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you aren't trying to give each letter a different background color, you can just specify CSS for each span like this:

```
.kkc-dni {background-color: red;}
```

Example here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/WAPds/

If you want each letter to have a different background color or other unique CSS, then you will have to wrap each letter in its own individual span.  You can do that programmatically using JS if you can't control the generated HTML.

Comment: But he wants the background to each letter:
"**I want to add a background colour to each letter inside that span.**"

Comment: @leoMestizo - he didn't say he wanted to give each letter a DIFFERENT background color.  He just said he wants to give each one a background color which this does.  You can't give each letter a different color without wrapping them separately.  I've updated my answer to be more clear how I was interpreting the question.

Comment: @jfriend00 It is not the different colour I am worried about it is because each character has it's own border radius.

So if you have one border radius around the span that is a different effect to having each character with its own border radius and some spacing in between.

Comment: @ChrisG-Jones - then you will have to wrap each letter individually.  Border-radius isn't a font property.  It's an element property.

Comment: If you want to add a border to each letter ONLY with CSS without modify the markup, that's not possible.

Comment: Ah thanks guys.

Will do some jQuery and modify the markup to wrap them each in a span.

Comment: @ChrisG-Jones you will have to do this (modifying the markup): [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/fg96x/). Otherwise with JavaScript.

Comment: @leoMestizo because the kkcountdown plugin all ready outputs the spans I am going to have to wrap each letter with a span with jQuery.
Am looking into this now.