# Different color to every character of the russian alphabet in a given text in CSS and/or Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to test "induced synesthesia" by coloring texts by individual characters. Each character in the russian alphabet should be mapped to a color, e.g. А is red, Б is blue and so on, so there would be a total of 33 colors. This process should be automatic.

The way I thought involves putting the whole text in a `div` element and getting it in Javascript, then separate each character and put a `<span class="letter">` around it with the correct letter, so for the word "два" the final text would be something like this:

```
<div class=text>
    <span class="д">д</span><span class="в">в</span><span class="а">а</a>
</div>
```

Question is, is there a better and/or shorter way to do it? I imagine a big enough text could even crash the browser.

Comment: You are going in right direction. it is the best solution.

Comment: [Here is a similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17517816/2930477) with background colors. You could change this to set the font color instead.

Comment: @Mr_Green which direction? he just have posted HTML

Comment: you can take a javascript array and can apply at run time

Comment: @Justcode why would he do at runtime when he is able to change the HTML and CSS?

Comment: @Mr_Green you're right but alternative is when you want to apply color randomly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though you can easily wrap each letter with a span in HTML, the below solution will be helpful if there are many letters or else if you want to save time, run this function in console to instantly wrap a span to each letter with a class name.

```
function addClassToLetters(element) {
    // runs if the passed element has no children elements in it.
    if (!element.children.length) {
        return element.innerHTML.replace(/(.)/g, function (x) {
            return "<span class='" + x + "'>" + x + "</span>";
        });
    }
    else{
        // do something if the element has child elements in it
        // or return the original html
    }
}
```

Comment: After all you agree to use javascript

Answer (score 0):

Here's a jQuery way to do it.

**1st Step:** Make a function to split the text to span like you did manually but now dynamically.

**2nd Step:** Give the class of the span the respective letter.

**3rd Step:** Write the css for all the letters to give their respective colors.

Here's the code :

**HTML :**

```
<div class="text">Test Message</div>
```

**jQuery :**

```
$.fn.texter = function() {
    var letters = $(this).html().split(""),
        text = "";

    for (var i in letters) {
        text += "<span class='"+letters[i]+"'>"+letters[i]+"</span>";
    }

    $(this).html(text);
};

$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".text").texter();
});
```

**CSS :**

```
.a {color: red;}
.b {color: green;}
.c {color: blue;}
.d {color: yellow;}
.e {color: magenta;}
```

Here's a Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/3d4j5cdq/