# Adding a <span> to each letter in responsive wordpress theme

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, themes

I want to create separate backgrounds for each letter in the site-description span within the header on the Wordpress responsive theme.

I have added a function in functions.php

```
<?php
/**
 * Setup Responsive Child Theme Functions
 */


 function site_description_spans() {

 echo 'Text within header'; // Replace this line with code from `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17517816/color-every-character-differently



}
add_action( 'responsive_in_header', 'site_description_spans' );
?>
```

This successfully targets within the header within the responsive theme
But then I tried to add the following code within this function from another Stack Exchange post by replacing the

```
echo 'text within header' //above
```

The link to the javascript function on stack exchange is here

[Color every character differently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17517816/color-every-character-differently)

and the relevant code is

```
 $('.site-description').find('span').each(function(){



var $el = $(this),
    text = $el.text(),
    len = text.length,
    newCont = '';

  for(var i=0; i<len; i++){
    var bgColor= '#'+ (Math.random() * 0xffffff).toString(16).substr(-6); 
    newCont += '<span style="background:'+bgColor+'">'+ text.charAt(i) +'</span>';
  }

  $el.html(newCont);

});
```

And it doesn't seem to work. Would be grateful for any suggestions.

Comment: What error you get in console?

Answer (score 0):

Now i'm not too sure on the outputted HTML but i'm going to take a wild guess, that this is how the HTML is being output:

```
<span class="site-description">
    Text within header
</span>
```

What you need if the code is to work as expected

```
<div class="site-description">
    <span>
        Text within header
    </span>
</div>
```

### Option 1 - Change HTML

Change your HTML code so that a `span` is contained within a `div` and the function to add the text is within the `span`

Something like this

```
<div class="site-description">
    <span>
        <!-- RUN FUNCTION HERE -->
    </span>
</div>
```

### Option 2 - Change jQuery

Change your jQuery function to something like this:

```
$('.site-description').each(function() {



  var $el = $(this),
    text = $el.text(),
    len = text.length,
    newCont = '';

  for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    var bgColor = '#' + (Math.random() * 0xffffff).toString(16).substr(-6);
    newCont += '<span style="background:' + bgColor + '">' + text.charAt(i) + '</span>';
  }

  $el.html(newCont);

});
```

Or generally just fix the first part of the query so that it finds the correct class or element.

Comment: Here is the relevant HTML snippet, sorry I forgot to post before. `<div id="logo">
    <span class="site-name"><a href="http://www.domain.com/" title="Site Title" rel="home">Site Title</a></span>
    <span class="site-description">Demo site to showcase new features</span>
   </div><!-- end of #logo -->

Answer (score 0):

Ok,

I have tried option 2 and just inserted it in the original function but I am not really sure what I am doing here. I understand what you suggested in option 2 and it looks like that would work, I am just not sure how to add it as a function in functions.php

This is what I have

```
function site_description_spans() {

$('.site-description').each(function() {



  var $el = $(this),
    text = $el.text(),
    len = text.length,
    newCont = '';

  for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    var bgColor = '#' + (Math.random() * 0xffffff).toString(16).substr(-6);
    newCont += '<span style="background:' + bgColor + '">' + text.charAt(i) + '</span>';
  }

  $el.html(newCont);

});

}
add_action( 'responsive_in_header', 'site_description_spans' );
?>
```

Trouble is that I get the following error with it

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting T_VARIABLE or '$' in /***/*****/public_html/*****/dev/wp-content/themes/responsive_child/functions.php on line 11
```