# Colouring letters, numbers in HTML document

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, react-native

How is it possible to add style (colors) to text in an html document in a letter by letter basis (by numbers and any symbol as well), to each letter a defined color is applied.

Think you have [grapheme-color synesthesia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grapheme%E2%80%93color_synesthesia), in this case I have, and want to make a text editor with your colors applied to glyphs. Although there are ready programs I want to enjoy doing one myself and practice my JavaScript skills. Later I am planning a reader also.

One way is to wrap every letter in an html element in another element, say a `span` and apply style by class name being related to the wrapped letters name. I will use same idea also in a React Native app.

Is there any other more efficient or more proper way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Basic regular expression with replace to add spans. You can replace the string with a function so you can do something more dynamic to determine the color.

```js
var ps = document.querySelectorAll("p");
[].forEach.call(ps, function (elem) {
  elem.innerHTML = elem.innerHTML.replace(/(\S)/g, "<span>$1</span>");
});
```

```css
span { 
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 20px; text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<p>Mary had a slice of bacon. It cost $0.75 and tasted great.</p>
<p>Bill had no bacon. He was sad!</p>
```

Other than doing the looping and replacing, I do not think there is another way of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

Below is the reference link,

**Change** this **span tag** in the **referenced** example,
ie. instead **background** give **color** in **style tag**

```
<span style="color:'+bgColor+'">'+ text.charAt(i) +'</span>
```

and

Change the **css** background:white

[Reference link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17517816/color-every-character-differently)