# Is it possible to make different colored text in html?

Tags: html

This is probably not what you think but I'm trying to make a “Welcome to _____” kind of thing. The way I want it to be is that “Welcome to” is in black and some of the name of the project is in green or something and the rest is black again. There is a bunch of stuff in HTML that I haven't learned yet so there is probably a simple solution.

I tried using the code

```
<h1>Welcome to</h1> <h1>Name</h1>
```

But that just put it on a different line so I don't know what to do.

Comment: Where did you get stuck? What have you tried? You say there's a lot you haven't learned yet, but what research have you undertaken?

Comment: I have searched for a couple of days and found nothing

Comment: So what are the exact requirements of any solution that might be accepted as correct? (This is a rhetorical question intended for you to edit your question to include those requirements there, not in comments.)

Comment: As @DavidThomas mentioned already in comment, there seems to be confusion in your question. In the original post, you mentioned wanting black text with certain parts of the project name in green. However, in a comment, you mentioned wanting it to be more colorful like the Google logo. Can you please clarify your requirements for us to better assist you?

Answer (score 1):

To achieve the desired effect of having "Welcome to" in black and the project name in a different color, you can use CSS (Cascading Style Sheets) to style the text. Here's an example of how you can modify your HTML code:

```
<style>
  .welcome-text {
    color: black;
  }
  
  .project-name {
    color: blue; /* You can change "blue" to any color you prefer */
  }
</style>

<h1><span class="welcome-text">Welcome to</span> <span class="project-name">Name</span></h1>
```

In the code above, we have added CSS styles to two classes: .welcome-text and .project-name. The color property is set to black for .welcome-text and blue (you can change this to any color you like) for .project-name. By wrapping the text in  tags and assigning them the respective classes, you can apply different styles to each part of the text.

This will give you the desired effect of having "Welcome to" in black and the project name in a different color, all on the same line.

Comment: But I want to make it more colorful. Like how the Google logo has a different color for each letter

Comment: "*I want to make it more colorful. Like how the Google logo has a different color for each letter*" - then you need to add that detail to the question, so that people can create a solution with this requirement in mind.

Comment: I understand correctly that you want the text to have more colors?

Answer (score -1):

You can use span in between the sentence and style it

```
<h1>Welcome to <span style="color: someColor;">Name</span></h1>
```

Comment: But I want to make it more colorful. Like how the Google logo has a different color for each letter

Comment: here is a good example
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17517816/color-every-character-differently